# Ruby on Rails "Couldnt find status id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm doing this treehouse project, some kind of social network built with ruby on rails (http://teamtreehouse.com/library/building-social-features-in-ruby-on-rails-2).

I was trying to make a user unable to update an existing status from another user and got stuck. This is my statuses_controller.rb:

```
  class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  before_action :set_status, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /statuses
  # GET /statuses.json
  def index
    @statuses = Status.order("created_at DESC").to_a
  end

  # GET /statuses/1
  # GET /statuses/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /statuses/new
  def new
    @status = Status.new
  end

  # GET /statuses/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /statuses
  # POST /statuses.json
  def create
    @status = current_user.statuses.new(status_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.save
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @status }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /statuses/1
  # PATCH/PUT /statuses/1.json
  def update
    @status = current_user.statuses.find(params[:id])
    params[:status].delete(:user_id) if params[:status].has_key?(:user_id)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @status.update(status_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /statuses/1
  # DELETE /statuses/1.json
  def destroy
    @status.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to statuses_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_status
      @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def status_params
      params.require(:status).permit(:content, :user_id)
    end
end
```

While testing this (if a user 'should update status for the current user when logged in'), I got the following error:

```
1) Error:
StatusesControllerTest#test_should_update_status_for_the_current_user_when_logged_in:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Status with id=980190962 [WHERE "statuses"."user_id" = ?]
app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:45:in `update'
test/controllers/statuses_controller_test.rb:76:in `block in <class:StatusesControllerTest>'

2) Error:
StatusesControllerTest#test_should_update_status_when_logged_in:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Status with id=980190962 [WHERE "statuses"."user_id" = ?]
app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:45:in `update'
test/controllers/statuses_controller_test.rb:70:in `block in <class:StatusesControllerTest>'

12 tests, 24 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

This is my statuses_controller_test.rb:

```
test "should update status when logged in" do
  sign_in users(:gustavo)
  put :update, id: @status, status: { content: @status.content }
  assert_redirected_to status_path(assigns(:status))
end

test "should update status for the current user when logged in" do
  sign_in users(:gustavo)
  put :update, id: @status, status: { content: @status.content, user_id: users(:paul).id }
  assert_redirected_to status_path(assigns(:status))
  assert_equal assigns(:status).user_id, users(:gustavo).id
end
```

And that's my fixture users.yml:

```
gustavo:
  first_name: "Gustavo"
  last_name: "Paiva"
  email: "gustavorpaiva@gmail.com"
  profile_name: "grpaiva"

paul:
  first_name: "Paul"
  last_name: "McCartney"
  email: "paulmccartney@gmail.com"
  profile_name: "paulpaul"
```

I'm using Rails 4.0.4, and I've already made some fixtures on treebook's code so it could work perfectly (i think it was made with Rails 2.x). Should that be the case or am I missing something here?

Ps.: This is my project link, before making this changes http://sheltered-everglades-2797.herokuapp.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try @status.id in the put method instead of just @status

```ruby
test "should update status when logged in" do
  sign_in users(:gustavo)
  put :update, id: @status.id, status: { content: @status.content }
  assert_redirected_to status_path(assigns(:status))
end
```

If that doesn't work, can you post the code for how is the @status object is built in the controller test?

Comment: Thanks tleish. But it didn't work. I'm updating the post with the whole status_controller.rb. Is that what you asked to do?